# Latex 1° page template setting

Tags: templates

I try to write an article  by using asme latex template.
I would like to create my first page like this asme example, but I don’t know how.
I using using the latex template for journal paper (with two column).
http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Stefano

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Have a look at the army corps of engineers template and maybe adjust that... [erdc](https://ctan.org/pkg/erdc )

Comment: If ASME provides a template, use it as specified; the final touches will be done by their copy editors.

Comment: thank you all, the code is the link that I already attached http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/. You can download it by click on 
"LaTeX template for ASME journal papers -- two column layout for review, version 1.0 " Thanks Again

Comment: As mentioned above, even if a journal has a LaTeX template, that does not mean that the output of that template is the same as that of the printed paper. Typically the paper will be re-typeset by the publisher. So if you are intending to submit a paper for publishing, don't mind the fact that it looks different from an already published paper.

Comment: Okk, thanks, but i don't send the publication to ASME, but I use this template for other purposes.... Thanks again and best regards

Comment: You can achieve the appearance you are seeking by using the newer ASME LaTeX template, [asmejour.cls](https://ctan.org/pkg/asmejour), which is in CTAN.